# (Angular 12) Search button response data is not show in template before Click the button twice

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular10, angular11, angular12

Here is my search input box and button

```
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input #text class="form-control" placeholder="Search Customer" required/>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info me-2" (click)="searchData(text)">Search</button>
```

Here is my component code i got the value in console

```
   searchData(text:any){
     this.service.searchCustomer(text.value).subscribe(
       response =>{
         this.list = response;
         console.log(this.list); 
         this.cData = this.list.data.model;
        }
  );
}
```

Here is my service that i return

```
    searchCustomer(text:string){
      let body ={"searchText":text}
       return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'/search-customer', body);
      }
```

Comment: Can you specify what error you faced?

Comment: Use ChangerefDetector , It will refresh your data binding. I am sure it will resolve your issue

Comment: @YongShun i did not display the data in template using one click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working fine I put an alert into search data this function and I got the alert which I put in that function

**With One Click**

you have to put in your constructor

```
constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

searchData(text:any){
 this.service.searchCustomer(text.value).subscribe(
   response =>{
     this.list = response;
     console.log(this.list); 
     this.cData = this.list.data.model;
     this.changeRef.detectChanges(); // this line detect changes
    })
;}
```

Comment: all things are ok but i need to render this data in html using one click.Thanks

Comment: ok so you have to add one line in your constructor 

`constructor(
    private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ){}`

in your click function after getting, data add this line 

`functionName(){
  // your response data after add this line
   this.changeRef.detectChanges();
}`

Comment: @divraj update your answer with code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I update the code which you ask can you check and let me know if you have any problem with that code.